# How to access a named resource from Application.Resources in code-behind?

Tags: c#, silverlight

In this Silverlight application, I am trying to access a resource from Application.Resources in a MainPage class. The resource has a x:Name attribute not a x:Key.

I know that I can assign a keyed resource from the Application.Resources by using the following line of code:

```cs
grid1.Background = (LinearGradientBrush)Application.Current.Resources["KeyedTwoColorGradient"];
```

Using this logic I tried to assign a named resource to my grid1.Background and used:

```cs
grid1.Background = ((LinearGradientBrush)Application.Current).Resources.NamedTwoColorGradient;
```

This line of code gives me an error:
Cannot convert type 'System.Windows.Application' to 'System.Windows.Media.LinearGradientBrush'

I have tried also different lines but nothing has worked. I could not find the answer from somewhere else so I am here with this question.

In addition, could someone tell me when it would be appropriate to use Named resources and when it would be better to use Keyed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters your brackets were in the wrong place in your example (you were actually casting an application object to a LinearBrush) e.g.:

```
 ((LinearGradientBrush)Application.Current)
```

but the "correct" syntax will auto-complete but will **not** compile:

```
(Application.Current as App).KeyedTwoColorGradient;
```

**The problem is that there is no designer.cs equivalent for App.xaml, unlike user controls, so named members are only visible to intellisense but actually have no code-behind property.**

You should use keys only for resources.

Comment: I see. Thank you. I am still very new to C# and even newer to Silverlight but this post helped me a lot. I figured it out already that I should avoid resource naming and prefer keying.

Comment: +1 However the syntax does not even "auto-complete", it would only auto complete if there were a `KeyedTwoColorGradient` field auto-generated into the App.g.i.cs file.  However this doesn't happen because the build action on "App.xaml" is "ApplicationDefinition" and that doesn't create fields for Named elements.

Comment: @AnthonyWJones: Apparently intellisense can work off the Xaml alone as *it does* auto-complete however I do have ReSharper which may be aiding me :)

Comment: @HiTech:  Perhaps, I don't use ReSharper so that may be the difference.  In my test I don't get any such intellisense for names in App.xaml.  Is Resharper trying to compensate for intellisense in code-behind requiring the xaml file to be saved to be complete?

Comment: @AnthonyWJones: Must be ReSharper then. It has some sort of super-intellisense so finds more info than the normal one. Cheers